# Stream backup from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, backup, file-transfer

I have a Linux server with almost no disk space left. I fact i there is not enough space left to write a full backup to the disk, so i wonder if there is a good way to stream the backup directly to my windows home PC and save it there.

Basically i want to know how i could transmit output from a pipe on Linux to a file on a remote Windows server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Windows end, do:

```
ssh user@linuxserver "tar cvzf - /stufftobackup" > backup.tgz
```

Obviously user will need read access to /stufftobackup.

Comment: Nice, i didn't think it would be so simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are the Windows and Linux systems on the same network? If you're just backing up a directory and not the system, you could just mount a Windows share in Linux (something like mount -t cifs //windows.system.ip/sharename /mnt/samba , first creating /mnt/samba) and save your files there.

Or you can use FUSE to mount a remote share over SSH as if it were local and again save data to the mount point.